# Foreach on XML returning string

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to read an XML file via PowerShell.

Sample XML:

```xml
<branches>
    <branch>refs/heads/master</branch>
    <branch Version="6.0.7">develop/4.0</branch>
</branches>
```

Sample code:

```bsh
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlfile)
foreach ($branch in $xml.branches.branch) {
    $version = $branch.Version
}
```

The problem is that the attribute `Version` is optional and PowerShell interprets the first occurrence of `branch` as a string. The second occurrence works fine. I need both of them to be an XmlElement. I have already tried casting `$xml.branches.branch` to an array of XmlElements with no success.

How can I transform to XmlElement?

Comment: Why not just `$branch.Version` instead of `$branch | Select -expand Version`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the suggestion I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SelectSingleNode()` with an [XPath expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) rather than dot-access:

```
$version = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//branches/branch/@Version').'#text'
```

Comment: I ended up using SelectNodes("//branch") and iterating through it, I was able to get xmlElements, marking as accepted